# Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos?

Tags: objective-c, crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x75cc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x713c pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1c8f0 abort + 180
3  Fordeal                        0xd7db4c __copy_helper_block_.70 + 257624
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x744c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x15be4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x163ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
```

Have no idea how to fix this crash?
and it's not plist of authority
have anyone help me ？